# How to send a message/ notification to a desktop client immediately

Tags: networking, push-notification

How can I notify a desktop client of something happening immediately (within a second of it happening?) Namely, I want something to happen on desktop when a certain event occurs on mobile.  Of course, notifying a server from mobile is trivial, but I do not know how to send a notification from the server to the desktop.

Keeping an open connection seems too expensive somehow, since I want the desktop app to *always* be running.  And polling the server every second also seems like it would lead to performance issues on the computer.  How can I resolve this issue?